# find Duplicates in Array scala

Tags: scala

Is there a better way to find duplicates in an Array which has better time & space complexity, below is what i have tried

I believe Time complexity is O(N) and space Complexity is O(1)

```
def findDuplicates(nums:Array[Int]):ArrayBuffer[Int] ={

    var buckets =new HashMap[Int,String]()
    var outputArr= new ArrayBuffer[Int]()

    nums.foreach(x=>
      if(buckets.contains(x) && buckets(x) == "Im Cool")
      {
        outputArr +=x
      }
      else
        buckets(x) = "Im Cool"

    )

    outputArr
  }
```

Comment: Is the result order important? e.g. input: `(4,5,6,6,4,6)`, result: `(6,4,6)`, or `(4,6,6)`, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Do you want to remove the duplicates? Do you want to know which values are duplicated? Do you need to prefer order?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez no preference on the order i want to return array of numbers which are repeated , output:(4,6)

Answer (score 2):

Both the time and space complexity of your algorithm is `O(N)`, where `N = |nums|`.

#### Time

HashMap operations `contains`, `put`, `get` all have an average `O(1)` time complexity, appending to an array also has an average `O(1)` complexity. You algorithm invokes `contains` and `get` `N` times and `put` and array append maximum `N` times. This gives `O(N)`.

#### Space

The size of `buckets` grows linearly with `N`. In a test case where `N` is twice as big, the size of `buckets` will be appr. twice as big, too. Same for `outputArr`. So this gives `O(N)`, too.

#### Optimization

Your approach is optimal in terms of the theoretical complexity. Because duplicate elements can be anywhere in the input array, you must read every element, unless you have some prior knowledge about the array. So the time complexity cannot be less than `O(N)`.

The output array may contain up to `N-1` elements (example: `[0, 0, 0]` returns `[0, 0]`), therefore the space complexity cannot be less than `O(N)`.

However, you can optimize your implementation, both in terms of actual speed and readability by using a HashSet for storing elements that you have already seen.

```
def findDuplicates(nums:Array[Int]):ArrayBuffer[Int] ={
    var buckets = new HashSet[Int]()
    var outputArr = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()

    nums.foreach(x=>
      if(buckets.contains(x)) {
        outputArr += x
      }
      else {
        buckets.add(x)
      }

    )

    outputArr
  }
```

This removes the magic `"Im Cool"` strings and saves the constant time of string comparisons.

Comment: thanks I think `buckets.insert` needs to be replaced with either `buckets+=` or `buckets.addOne` as `buckets.insert` is throwing compiler error if i use mutable Hashset

Comment: @shiv455 I've updated my answer. The correct method name is `add` or `+=`.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, it is possible to write C code in the Scala language, but it's not a good way to learn Scala style.

Adhering to FP principles can, sometimes, make it even more difficult to solve LeetCode challenges.

But Scala can be a pretty good choice when playing [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf).

```
def findDuplicates(nums:Array[Int]):Array[Int] =
  nums diff nums.distinct
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and elegant solution would be this:

```
def getDuplicates[T](data: List[T]): List[T] =
  data
    .groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
    .iterator
    .collect {
       case (x, count) if (count > 1) => x
    }.toList
```

The time complexity is **O(N)** since it does two traversals of the data.
A first one to compute the number of times each element was present and a second one to filter and conserve elements that appear at least two times.

---

BTW, I would stay away from **Arrays** unless you really need to.
**Arrays** are to be avoided because they are mutable and invariant, also they are not proper collections, they are a JVM primitive and using them effectively is complex.

Comment: Can you please explain  the time & space complexity for this ? also any specific reason why you recommend to stay away from Array ? does it have any implications if the input array is large?

Comment: also whats identity variable inside groupMapreduce fucntion

Comment: @shiv455 Edited the answer to include time complexity and an explanation fo why arrays are to be avoided. I do not know how to calculate space complexity so sorry about that. Finally, `identity` is not a variabel. is a defined function; it is equivalent to `x => x`

Answer (score 0):

```
def getDuplicates[T](nums: Array[T]): List[T] = {
    nums.foldLeft(Map.empty[T, Int])((a,b) => a.updated(b, a.getOrElse(b, 0) + 1))
      .filter(_._2 > 1).flatMap(e => List.fill(e._2 - 1)(e._1)).toList
  }
```

Time-Complexity: O(N)
Space-Complexity: O(N) Worst Case Only If Output Array Is Not Considered. If Considered Space Complexity will be O(1).

Comment: Doesn't produce the same result as OP's code. Try `Array(1,2,1,3,1)`.

Comment: @jwvh, what's the expected?